# Banging sounds coming in front of my car

Tags: engine, transmission, automatic-transmission, nissan, noise

I'm having a banging sounds coming from the front of my car.

Usually they appear after 5-10 meters when I'm driving. It's like one small knock and then around 5-6 more knocks and then they stop until the end of the journey.

They started to appear when the engine is cold, but now I hear them more often when I'm just starting the drive.

I've took the car to the mechanic and he says he didn't found any vibration or strange thing with my engine. He advised to change the tyres but it actually didn't helped.

What could it possible be?

My car:
Nissan Tiida, 2006, Automatic transmission.

Comment: Does the position of the steering, or the rate you accelerate affect the knocking in any way?

Comment: Probably... if I'm starting driving very slowly I don't hear until I start to accelerate faster.

Comment: I've read somewhere that it could be ABS testing (people say it could happen with Nissan cars), but I don't know is it true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the actual reason is ABS sensor which is known to be glitchy in Nissan cars. I've read that it could be testing the ABS when the car is starting to move.

The reason why I think this way is because when I've occasionally pushed the breaks too hard I heard the same sounds, and the brake pad was knocking as it should do when the ABS is working.

Answer (score 1):

The two immediate things that comes to mind for me:

1. CV joints, but this will get better and worse according to the position of the steering wheel.
2. This happened on my FIL's car. He lost the top bolt on the torque plate (to which the brake caliper is attached). This caused the entire caliper to rotate away under certain conditions and cause a knocking/grinding sound.